# Event for when user clicks/releases mouse button globally

Tags: c#, events

Hey guys i was wondering if there was a way to detect if the user has clicked the mouse down and also if they have released it? Currently I am trying to use:

```
   private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        start_x = e.X;
        start_y = e.Y;

        MessageBox.Show(start_x.ToString() + " : " + start_y.ToString());

    }
```

But that only works when clicking inside the form. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what else you want.......are you trying to detect user click outside your form ot not....

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it very well. I'm trying to detect whether or not the user has click/released the mouse button. Inside, or outside the form.

Comment: see [this page about hooking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959.aspx#wh_mouse_llhook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this [library](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/).

It allows you to easily register global keyboard & mouse hooks and handle them like any other .NET mouse / keyboard event.

Also CodeProject has a [ton](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) of [reading](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook) [material](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET) on this